# Run a program for multiple files in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to run multiple jobs at once. I have written a script which runs this job one by one, but I want to submit all of them at once. It should not wait for the former job to finish. The script is as follows,

```
#!/bin/bash --login

# Default job location in current directory

#SBATCH -p multicore
#SBATCH -n 4 # Use 4 cores

module load gaussian/g16c01_em64t

export GAUSS_SCRDIR=/scratch/$USER/gau_temp_$JOB_ID
mkdir -p $GAUSS_SCRDIR
export GAUSS_PDEF=$NSLOTS

jobnames=($(seq 1 1 100))

for i in ${jobnames[@]}; do
$g16root/g16/g16 < "job_"${i}".gjf" > "job_"${i}".out"
done
```

The input files for the job are in the same directory with the names job_1.gjf,job_2.gjf...job_100.gjf. This code runs well with sequential job runs.

Comment: Not an answer because I don't really know, but GNU `parallel` may suit you

Comment: Do you know about `&`? If you run `cmd &`, that `cmd` will execute in background and you can run any number of jobs this way.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was trying with GNU parallel, it is not installed and I do not have rights to install it. Also I tried with & at the end of $g16root/g16/g16 < "job_"${i}".gjf" > "job_"${i}".out" & which shows empty output files. The jobs do not run, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments indicate, you need to use `&` to put the jobs into the background if you are just using bash.

Change

```
for i in ${jobnames[@]}; do
$g16root/g16/g16 < "job_"${i}".gjf" > "job_"${i}".out"
done
```

to

```
for i in ${jobnames[@]}; do
    $g16root/g16/g16 < "job_"${i}".gjf" > "job_"${i}".out" &
done
wait
```

to allow for some indentation in the loop, making the jobs run in parallel, and waiting at the end for them all to finish

Whilst you are doing this I would be inclined to change

```
jobnames=($(seq 1 1 100))

for i in ${jobnames[@]}; do
```

to

```
for i in {1..100}; do
```

to remove the need for the `seq` utility and just use the bash builtin, since this question is tagged as `bash`.